# How can I stop certain skills from adding to the level up counter?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to be able to stop smithing and alchemy from adding to my level, but I still want the skill in itself to level up. Preferably using *tesvedit*, I can't get *uncapper* to work

Comment: Uuummmm... Why?

Comment: @Ben He wants to have his level as low as possible and be able to make the strongest armor and weapons. That way, he'll have the strongest items but the enemies in the world won't be stronger. For instance, he'll only have to face regular Draugr and he'll never see any Draugr Deathlords.

Comment: Are you playing on PC or console?

Comment: @Ciacciu: PC: As far as I know console users are unable to use tesvedit.

Comment: @ChaseC: Actually it is because I think you should not level up by working in the safety of the city but only by actually doing something.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to do that. At least not without coding. The system might be hardcoded. Does the uncapper do what you want? Because then you might want to figure out why the uncapper doesn't work. As that isn't that hard.

Comment: @Telvannizer, can't you just level up your skills and never, ever go-to the skills menu?

Comment: Are you open to mods, instead? I don't know of any that do exactly what you want, but there is one that could help

Comment: @Finn Rayment: I would still gain levels by doing smithing, and that is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: @Ids: Here's the problem with uncapper: I had set SkillExpGainMults to 0.4 for alchemy, smithing, speech, and Enchanting and 0.5 for all others because I do not like lvling up too fast. Then I set PCLevelSkillExpMults to 0.0. for alchemy, smithing, speech, and Enchanting and left the others untouched. Started a new game, and found out that I got to lvl 2 just by reading 2 skill books. The thing with stopping certain skills from adding to level worked fine, but it seems that it makes the other skills add too much to player lvl.

Comment: @Ciacciu: What mod(s)?

Comment: @Telvannizer, ahh yes, I just forgot sorry, going to the skills menu gives you HP/ST/MG, had a mind blank thinking it gives you the actual level. xD

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ *this is the best possible solution* been what I said?

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you're asking for, but the [Character creation overhaul](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/21587/?) allows you to choose your "major" and "minor" skills, similar to older TES games.

What this means is that major skills are the most important for levelling, then come minor, then not chosen. This allows you to *spec* your character(s).

I suggest choosing as major and possibly minor some skills that you want to use but are hard to level, like Destruction if you play a mage. I also suggest not taking sneak, in all my games that skill skyrocketed, and having it as a Major or even Minor means getting a lot of levels,especially if you do the thieves' guild quest.

The mod specifies this, but you can select birthsign and Class even on an already started character.

I'll paste here from the mod's "Known Issues" section:

> Using CCO on existing characters may initially decrease some skills below the required level for perks that you have already obtained. These perks are still usable, but if you wish to remove them you will have to use a perk removal mod such as Ishs Respec Mod.
>   When using the Dynamic Skill Progression module, racial skill rate bonuses are applied based on vanilla Skyrim races' starting skills, not based on other mod's. For example, if mod X gives Imperials a +10 starting skill bonus to Speech, you will not also receive a skill rate bonus to Speech since Imperials do not normally get a starting skill bonus in vanilla Skyrim.
>   If you have mods that alter birthsigns, CCO will use those changes, but CCO's birthsign descriptions may not be accurate. <

Comment: I know this mod,and I downloaded it to see if I could dope out how he has done it. But he only uses scripts, and I know nothing of those. But thx!

Comment: Seeing as how scripts are how mods work, and seeing how a mod will do what you want with least fuss... +1 to this.

Answer (score 0):

(using uncapper) How did you install uncapper? Did you use Nexus? You need to have SKSE installed in order to use uncapper. Have you installed that as well?

You need to modify the **SKSE_Elys_Uncapper.ini** file in your SKSE plug-ins folder. Mine is in E:\Games\Steam\SteamApps\common\skyrim\Data\SKSE\Plugins. I simply used Notepadd++ to edit the file.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGnQIiNVqA) youtube video will help with the installation of SKSE, should you not have that installed.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OlkSTjRzho) youtube video will help with the installation of uncapper.

That being said, using a "too low" number can indeed crash the game, so be weary with using 0 for fSmithing.